# Write a function to calculate the square of the first k elements of a vector

Tags: r

I am trying to calculate the square of the first `k` elements of a vector `v`.

If `k` is greater than the length of the vector `n`, then set `k = n`.

```
myfun1 = function(v,k){ 
   p = ifelse(k > length(v), k = length(v), v[1:k]^2)
   return(p)
}

myfun1(v=seq(1,20,by=0.5), k=10)
```

When I run the code it gives me this error:

> Error in ifelse(k > length(v), k = length(v), v[1:k]^2) : 
>     unused argument (k = length(v))

Can anyone help to resolve this?

Answer (score 3):

`k = length(v)` inside your `ifelse` does not make sense. Here's a simpler approach -

```
myfun1 <- function(v, k) {
  v[1:min(k, length(v))]^2
}

myfun1(1:10, 5)
[1]  1  4  9 16 25

myfun1(1:10, 15)
[1]   1   4   9  16  25  36  49  64  81 100
```

Thanks to @josliber, here's another simple way to do this -

```
myfun1 <- function(v, k) {
  head(v, k)^2
}
```

Comment: *Does not make sense.* Please be **much more detailed** about why OP's code not working.